# Catenate dictionary value in RobotFramework

Tags: dictionary, xpath, robotframework

is there any way how to catenate a dictionary value in RobotFramework?
I have a limit of 180chars/line and would like to create a dictionary where the the value of it exceeds those 180chars. Is there any way how to catenate that so it is not treated as another line/key.In the image attached, it is treated as two different key/value relations.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PThxb.png)

Cant figure out a way on how to. If there even is a way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to create variable first and assign long string to it. After assign variable as value of dictionary key. For example:

```
*** Variables ***
${var}    Long
...       text
...       goes here
&{dict)   first=${var}    second=Second value
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, that's what I have done, initally. I was wondering if there is a way to do that inside the dictionary. Appreciate your answer anyway.